# Spring Security error

Tags: spring, spring-security

Hi i am new to spring security and trying to apply authentication and authorization through spring security.

While running the application i am getting this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
```

web.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>bsolPortalWebApp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-context.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/config/spring-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/config/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

     <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

my spring-security.xml file is

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/PoolB/*"  requires-channel="http"          access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />        
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/PoolB/Welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />                            
logout logout-success-url="/logout" />           
</http>
    <authentication-manager> 
    <authentication-provider> 
    <user-service> 
    <user name="abc" password="abc" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
    <user name="xyz" password="xyz" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
    </user-service> 
    </authentication-provider> 
    </authentication-manager>   
    </beans:beans>
```

login.jsp file is :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>

<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/background.css"  rel="stylesheet" >

  <style>
  .errorblock {
color: #ff0000;
background-color: #ffEEEE;
border: 3px solid #ff0000;
padding: 8px;
margin: 16px;
    margin-right:500px;
    margin-left:500px;
    }
   </style> 

</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password (Authentication with Database)</h3>
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
<div class="errorblock">
      Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
   ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
</div>
</c:if>                 
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
<table  align="center">
        <tr>
    <td>User:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='j_username'  value='' id='uname'>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='j_password'   id='pword'/>
    </td>
    </tr>           
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
    <td><input name="reset" type="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Welcome.jsp file is :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO- 8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hi U R Succesfully Loged in.
<br/>
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
<p>
<a href="..../ScorpioWebApp/PoolB/insert">InsertRecord</a>
</p>
</security:authorize>
<a href="..../ScorpioWebApp/PoolB/View">RetriveRecord</a>
</body>
```

and the added jars are:

```
1.com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
2.com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar
3.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
4.jstl-1.2.jar
5.log4j-1.2.11.jar
6.log4j.jar
7.spring-aop-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
8.spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
9.spring-aspects-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
10.spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
11.spring-build-src-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
12.spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
13.spring-context-support-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
14.spring-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
15.spring-expression-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
16.spring-instrument-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
17.spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
18.spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
19.spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
20.spring-mobile-device-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
21.spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
22.spring-oxm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
23.spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
24.spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
25.spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
26.spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
27.spring-struts-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
28.spring-test-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
29.spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
30.spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
31.spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
32.spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
33.sqljdbc4.jar
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue..

```
    It was the problem with jar only. I added 3.1.0 version of all spring security jars and as per the suggestiong from other users added the following bean to spring configuration

 <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.exp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have Spring Security 3.0.x dependencies added to your classpath while you also use `security-taglibs-3.1.0.RELEASE`. 
Try using Spring Security 3.1.x for all the dependencies

The class `SecurityExpressionHandler` was added to Spring Security 3.1

**UPDATE**

You also need to update the xsd references in spring.security.xml

and add the following bean to spring configuration

```
<bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

Comment: Hi I corrected the jar dependencies now I am using 3.1.0 version for all the spring security jars after that while running I am getting "HTTP Status 404 Exception". Please let me know if anything else I need to change. The strange thing for me is once I am using the old jars then I am not getting this error and able to see the login page  but after adding spring security 3.1.0 jars I am getting this error..

Comment: In spring-security.xml, try changing all references to spring 3.0 to spring 3.1 and see if that helps

Comment: Yes as per your suggestion I changed all references to 3.1.           springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security 3.1.xsd">      these two lines i modified in my spring-security.xml file.

Comment: You should update your question with the latest steps you took as well as post the latest error so all users can now know what the problem is

Comment: Great! Could you please mark the answer as correct so future users will know that it's the correct solution without reading through the comments. Thanks :)